# Asp.net dynamic compilation

Tags: asp.net, web-services

With Asp.net web sites and ASMX web services, can some explain what can change once an application has been deployed.

For web sites, I can see that the you can change the aspx files but for web services, I am not sure what can be changed. Any real-world examples of where changing files and dynamic compilation is useful?.

JD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deploying the application you can change anything you want to in there. You can change .aspx pages, you can add / remove dlls from the bin folder, you can add / remove code files from the app_code folder, you can add remove stuff from the app_data folder, you can obviously add remove the .asmx files for the web service. I don't see any reason why you cant change anything. go ahead and try changing these things. When you run the code after changes the website will compile again automatically. The things i wrote are written considering that you have deployed the whole code for the website and not a published site !

Comment: The last point you made about having all your code for the web site and not a published site, can you elaborate a bit more?